# How Do I extract the 5th and 6th rightmost characters from excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to extract the 5th and 6th rightmost characters from excel. How do I do that?

I have tried to use the mid function in excel, but it takes the reference from the first most cell

I want to extract Numbers 30, 29, 20 and 28 respectively

```
Days
2 months, 30 days
12 months, 29 days
112 months, 20 days
3 months, 28 days
```

Expected results: 
30
29
20
28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the date is in cell A2, you can make use of LEFT() and RIGHT()

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,7), 2)
```

Or using LEN() to get the length of string and use MID() to start with position = Length - 6

```
=MID(A2, LEN(A2)-6, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following formula given that you want to return the **third** word within the text string. Drag it down to apply across.

```
=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[3]")
```

[image: Solution]

For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).